# Simple way to continue writing a list? (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, html-lists

```
 <li>ThisSpecific1</li>
 <li></li>
```

What is the quickest/easiest way to go from the "1" to the next line to continue writing other stuff in the list?

Comment: you don't show html text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think the fastest would be `Ctrl+Left Arrow` to go to the beginning of the word and then `Down Arrow` to go to the line below. But personally I **wouldn't** have typed the 2nd `<li>` beforehand, so after the "1" I would do `Ctrl+Enter` to go to the next line and then type `<li>`.

P.S If you are using the emmet abbreviation of vscode, let's say `li*5` then vscode lets you cycle through them with `Tab` and `Shift+Tab`.